# Rails/Date: Do not use `to_time` on Date objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I converted my ERB to Slim and getting hit with linter issues. I'm getting

> Rails/Date: Do not use `to_time` on Date objects, because they know nothing about the time zone

The code in question is actually:

```
=@product.updated_at.to_time.strftime('%B %e @ %l:%M %p')
```

The data itself is actually: 2018-11-16 12:40:20.12345. My thought was to just try using .zone.today. Which results in

> undefined method `today' for "EDT":String

So I thought I'll use .current/.current.strftime('%B %e @ %l:%M %p') and it results in

> undefined method `current' for both attempts

I went into my application.rb and made sure I had:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you should just do:

```
@product.updated_at.strftime('%B %e @ %l:%M %p')
```

If I do that on one of my records, I get:

```
"November 12 @  9:26 AM"
```

Comment: Yeah. I banged my head on the wall for no reason

Comment: It happens from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

In some point of the work, I got some errors *(like: "undefined method 'strftime' for \"2019-01-25T18:40:25.536Z\":String\nDid you mean?  strip")* using `...updated_at.strftime` and some Rubocop warnings with `to_time`, so I solved my issues without warnings only with **`to_datetime`**.